# How do you show an image larger than the browser window without scrollbars and retain the whole image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to center an image in the browser window and apply a 3D transformation to it. This all works fine until the image is larger than the browser window, in which case I lose the parts of the image that would be off the screen, even though after the transformation, the entire image would fit in the browser window. I don't want to show scrollbars. If I make it a background image, I can transform the div, but I lose the parts of the image that would be off the screen if it was not transformed.

Is it possible to show an image larger than the browser window without getting scrollbars?

Comment: can you show your code for more detail

Comment: Are you asking how to get a 3 pound image in a 2 pound sack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started from scratch with a small example and managed to get it working by using `overflow: hidden;` on a div that contained a div that contained the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the CSS3 Background Size property?

You can read about it [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/). I believe that if you use the property

```
background-size:cover;
```

Along with it's `webkit` and `moz-webkit`, you should get the result you're looking for. Try it and let me know, and if not that link there should be useful.

Hope it helps! :D